# Avoid navigate through directories without permissions

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm coding a powershell script in order to search recursively through different folders, looking into each one some specific files. When I run the following command, I got some error because my user can't access some of the files/directories:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File 'E:\\' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The problem is that in $files, all files get stored, even if my user don't have access to them. Which is the best way to prevent that?

I was thinking about checking the ACL of every file and do some test, but I don't know if there is a more simple and/or elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the account you are using is in the "users" group. You may have to correlate that by using the Edit Local Users and Groups program. those will sometimes get "list folder contents", maybe try editing the permissions to remove that for the user and see if you get different results.

Comment: I know that the user does not have the appropiate permissions to access the folder, and that's fine. I just don't want those files/folders to be storaged in the `$files` variable.

Comment: when you say access, do you mean "open and return data". "Read" and "list" are two different permissions. Does the user, based on the user permissions or any group they are in have List permission? I tried to replicate this by using gci on a directory I know my account does not have read or list permission on and I got an error as expected. You need to look at the folder permissions (top-down) and you will probably see your user with "list" on that, or a higher level, directory, which is why you are getting those files returned by PS.